# Force Lucene.Net to match all keywords

Tags: c#, .net, lucene

I'm using [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) to search a database of products, however when I search for "grey usb mouse" the system returns results like "usb mouse" and "usb camera". How do I force Lucene to match all keywords, and skip products that don't have all keywords? The only related answer I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255561/1294758) but I don't really understand it.

This is my code:

```
// connect to index
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
var searcher new IndexSearcher(FSDirectory.Open(index_path));

// search and list results
var parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "title", analyzer);
var query = parser.Parse(search_term);
var results = searcher.Search(query, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the "AND" keyword between search terms to force lucene to "match all".

For this query:

> grey usb mouse

Convert it to this before passing it to Lucene:

> grey AND usb AND mouse

Ref : [Advanced queries with Lucene.NET](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/07/03/advanced-queries-with-lucene-net/)